# Select k numbers maximizing sum of pairwise xor

Tags: algorithm

Given a range `[l, r]` (where `l < r`), and a number `k` (where `k <= r - l`), I want to select a set `S` of `k` distinct numbers in `[l, r]` which maximizes the sum of pairwise xors. For example, if `[l, r] = [2, 10]` and `k = 3` and we choose `S = {4, 5, 6}`, the sum of xors is `d(4, 5) + d(4, 6) + d(5, 6) = 1 + 1 + 2 = 4`.

Here's my thinking so far: in `[l, r]`, for each bit index `i` less than or equal to the index of the highest set bit in `r`, the number of elements in `S ^ S` with the `i`th bit set is equal to `j * (k-j)`, where `j` is the count of the elements in `S` with the `i`th bit set. To optimize this we want to select `S` such that, for each bit `i`, `S` contains `k/2` elements with the `i`th bit set. This is easy for `k = 2`, but I'm stuck on generalizing this for `k > 2`.

Comment: Are there upper limits on `r-l` and `k`?

Comment: How do you calculate the Hamming distance between two numbers?

Comment: Let's use `l < r < 2^32`, `k <= r-l`. Sorry, reformulated in terms of `xor`.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance it seems that there is no algebraic solution for this problem. I mean, this seems like a *NP-hard* problem (a optimizational problem) that is not solvable in polynomial time.

As almost always possible one can brute force through the feasible space.

Intuitively, I can suggest to look into [Locality Sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). In **LSH** one normally tries to find similarities between two sets. But in you case, you can abuse this algorithm in the following sense.

- The domain is subdivided into few buckets.
- You sample randomly points in the space `[l,r]`.
- High probable points (large Hamming distance) are placed in the buckets.
- In the end you brute force in the most probable bucket.

In the end one can expect that points with large Hamming distances should be in the same neighborhood (that's why the name *Locality Sensitive Hashing*). However, it is just an idea.